# Programmatically make a UITabBarController with multiple tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to Objective-C and I've pieced together a starting point from other online sources. I want to programmatically make a tab bar controller with multiple tabs.
This is the code I currently have in `AppDelegate.m` method of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController * firstTab= [[UIViewController alloc] init ];
    UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

    UIViewController *secondTab = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But all it shows is a black screen with gray outlines on the top and bottom of the screen. What do I need to add to have the tabs visible and with different names? Will clicking the tab automatically shift to a new screen with an animation or do I need to put in code for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is blank because the view controllers do not have any information..

I modified your snippet to add some background color and title.. you should see them now :-)

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController * firstTab= [[UIViewController alloc] init ];
[firstTab.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
firstTab.title = @"firstTab";
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

UIViewController *secondTab = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[secondTab.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
secondTab.title = @"secondTab";
UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];

tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP's code should at least show empty tabs and an empty nav bar for the currently selected tab. Your answer doesn't address whatever issue is causing a black screen and gray bars.

Comment: @rmaddy the black screen is because the view of both the viewController do not have any background color.. I think he refers the navbar and  tabBar as gray bars.. they are empty because the viewcontrollers do not have a title.. I tested the snipped he posted and i posted.